# sum of positive elements of relatively convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If a series is relatively convergent, what can we say about the sum of all its positive elements?
Will it be also convergent?

Comment: If a series is conditionally convergent, then both the series of positive terms and series of negative terms diverge.

Comment: No, consider the series $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{-1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-1}{2}+...$. The positive terms are the harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: ah of course, thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot :)